# c# label not dragging:

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

When I try and drag label into the rich text box, the icon stays as rejected. My labels are in a panel, separate from the rich text box. How can I get the text from the label to copy into the rich text box? Right now I get the circle with a line as though I hadn't set txtText.AllowDrop to true, but I did right there at the form load.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found out that the `RichTextBox` doesn't have the standard drag-n-drop implementation. I has a property called `EnableAutoDragDrop`, just set this to `true`, it will handle everything automatically. You don't need any event registering for it except this one:

```
richTextBox1.EnableAutoDragDrop = true; //Just this even without AllowDrop = true
//RichTextBox doesn't even have DragOver event exposed, we have to cast it to Control to expose the base DragOver event
((Control)richTextBox1).DragOver += (s, e) => 
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
};
```

Without registering the DragOver event handler, you have to use (hold down/press) the Control key while doing drag-n-drop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but replacing my lblWord_MouseDown event with yours yielded no change.

Comment: @AuntJamaima the default `SetText("")` with 1 argument set the text as `Unicode format` while you check for the `ANSI format` in the `DragEnter` event handler. I updated the code and it should work now.

Comment: I made your change with no difference in behavior in the application. I've now posted the entire code. The textbox is a rich text box. I have a different version of a very similar application that seems to work with a regular text box. Could that make a difference.

Comment: @AuntJamaima OK, I updated the answer, that's the problem of `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Thank you. I added the call in the form load and it's works, albeit differently than a regular text box for sure. Thanks very much.